# Is this a correct way of using dependencies in python

Tags: python, dependency-injection

I am learning python and I am facing a dilemma:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractproperty, abstractmethod
import jsocket
from acme.core import StatusCode, Direction
import acme.db as db


class ModuleThread(jsocket.ServerFactoryThread):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    @abstractproperty
    def module_name(self):
        pass

    @abstractproperty
    def _db_model(self):
        pass

    def __init__(self):
        super(ModuleThread, self).__init__()
        self.code = StatusCode.PENDING
        self.status = None

    def _get_config_for_domain(self, domain, direction):

        # here I want to be sure that my db model is an instance
        # of a pewee model
        print self._db_model


class CheckMxThread(ModuleThread):
    @property
    def module_name(self):
        return 'check_mx'

    @property
    def _db_model(self):
        return db.ModMx
```

And the call

```
CheckMxThread()._get_config_for_domain('nocheck.mx', Direction.INCOMING)
```

I want to be sure that when using `self._db_model` I get an instance of Pewee Model, how should I handle this:

- directly by using the top import like I've done
- Injecting `db` package in the ModuleThread class and using later as `self.db.ModMx` in child classes ?

Answer (score 0):

You can verify this by using `isinstance`:

```
@property
def _db_model(self):
    if not instanceof(self, db.ModMx):
        raise IOError('can not use this instance type')
```

This work with child inhertance, example:

```
>>> class A:
...     pass

>>> class B(A):
...     pass

>>> b = B()
>>> isinstance(b, A)
True
```